# How to load WebWorker from local in WKWebView

Tags: wkwebview, web-worker

I rebuild an iOS app from a Vue.js app. It uses a `WebWorker` to execute a script in the background.
I confirmed that `npm run serve` on the local could run the app.
So the following process is to run the app in a `WKWebView`.

The app loads the files from a local device. The files such as index.html and main.js could be loaded and shown correctly.

```swift
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
webView.load(request)
```

However, the worker seems not to be loaded. The worker script is located in the same directory to index.html.

```js
// in my script
this.worker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

I also tried running a quite simple HTTP Web server to load worker.js.

```swift
guard let listener = try? NWListener(using: .tcp, on: NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: 52525)) else {
    print("### Error.")
    self.listener = nil
    return
}
listener.newConnectionHandler = { connection in
    connection.start(queue: .main)
    connection.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
        switch state {
        case .ready:
            connection.send(content:
("""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 86810
Content-Type: application/javascript


""".replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\r\n") + worker).data(using: .utf8), completion: .idempotent)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
listener.start(queue: .main)
self.listener = listener
```

Safari in iOS Simulator could get worker.js and show its content.

```js
// the app can send a response by HTTP.
this.worker = new Worker('http://localhost:52525/worker.js');
```

However, the error message said `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` How can I use a `WebWorker` in `WKWebView`? Is any configuration needed?

Comment: iOS and webkit have some isues with web workers, unfortunately. The biggest I know of being thst it's the only modern browser not to support BroadcastChannel. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=161472

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#embedded_workers) page, a script tag with `type="text/js-worker"` can be used for the alternative of worker.js file.

```html
<script id="worker" type="text/js-worker">
<!-- the contents of worker.js -->
</script>
```

```js
const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([document.getElementById("worker").textContent], {
        type: "application/javascript",
    })
));
```

I tried this approach, and then the worker could run.